# sudo apt-get update fails. Could not resolve ‘archiveubuntu.digital.local’

Tags: apt, 18.04, localrepository

I have problem with doing sudo apt-get update.
I got the following message:

```
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://package.perforce.com/apt/ubuntu trusty InRelease                  
Hit:3 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease              
Err:4 http://archiveubuntu.digital.local/ubuntu bionic InRelease               
Could not resolve ‘archiveubuntu.digital.local’
Err:5 http://archiveubuntu.digital.local/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Could not resolve ‘archiveubuntu.digital.local’
Err:6 http://archiveubuntu.digital.local/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Could not resolve ‘archiveubuntu.digital.local’
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archiveubuntu.digital.local/ubuntu/dists/bionic        /InRelease  Could not resolve ‘archiveubuntu.digital.local’
W: Failed to fetch http://archiveubuntu.digital.local/ubuntu/dists/bionic-     updates/InRelease  Could not resolve ‘archiveubuntu.digital.local’
W: Failed to fetch http://archiveubuntu.digital.local/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve ‘archiveubuntu.digital.local’
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

OS info

```
>>> uname -a
Linux 4.15.0-29-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 17 15:39:52 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm confused on what the archiveubuntu.digital.local is. How can I fix it?

Comment: Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and remove these entries or open software and updates app and uncheck the repos

Comment: "archiveubuntu.digital.local" is a server from where your Ubuntu PC downloads updates. For some reason it's unavailable now. Change the download server from the app **Software & Updates**.

Comment: Thanks! Should I check these entries again later on? They are there for a purpose, aren't they?

Comment: You can check whenever you want. But it's highly recommended that you check it ASAP.

Comment: Ok, sorry for bothering, but do I understand correctly? There is an error on the server's side. And it is supposed to be fixed. One option is to change the server. Am I right?

Comment: The error can be seen as an error on the server side... but the server archiveubuntu.digital.local is no more available and probably never will be. It says .local at the end which means it's not valid on the internet, only on the network where someone has setup this machine. Please have a look here for restoring the default package sources : https://askubuntu.com/a/192388/454520